# Simple URL cleaning

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to do some basic url cleaning, so that

```
www.google.com
www.google.com/
http://google.com
http://google.com/
https://google.com
https://google.com/
```

are replaced by `http://www.google.com` (or `https://www.google.com` in case when `https://` is at the beginning).

Basically I'd like to check if there is `http/https` at the beginning and `/` at the end in one regexp.

I was trying something like this:

`"https://google.com".match(/^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)(.*)(\/)*$/)` in this case I get: 
`=> #<MatchData "https://google.com" 1:"https://" 2:"google.com" 3:nil>` 
which is good.

Unfortunately for:

`"https://google.com/".match(/^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)(.*)(\/)*$/)` I get: 
`=> #<MatchData "https://google.com/" 1:"https://" 2:"google.com/" 3:nil>` and would like to have `2:"google.com" 3:"/"`

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: By the way, how are you treating the last url with the extra white space?

Comment: Good question, thanks. Will work on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's obvious if you spot the mistake ;)

You were trying:

```
^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)(.*)(\/)*$
```

The answer is to use:

```
^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)(.*?)(\/)*$
```

This makes the operator "non-greedy", so the tailing forward slash doesn't get swallowed up by the "." operator.

EDIT:

In fact, you should really be using:

```
^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(www\.)?(.*?)(\/)*$
```

That way, you will also match your first two examples, which don't have a "http(s)://" in them. You are also splitting out the value/existence of the "www" part. In action: http://www.rubular.com/r/VUoIUqCzzX

EDIT2:

I was bored and wanted to perfect this :P

Here you go:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(.*?)\/?$
```

Now, all you need to do is replace your website with the first match (or "http://", if nil), then "www.", then the second match.

In action: http://www.rubular.com/r/YLeO5cXcck

(18 months later) EDIT:

Check out my awesome ruby gem that will help solve your problems!

https://github.com/tom-lord/regexp-examples

```
/(https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?google\.com\/?/.examples # => 
  ["google.com",
   "google.com/",
   "www.google.com",
   "www.google.com/",
   "http://google.com",
   "http://google.com/",
   "http://www.google.com",
   "http://www.google.com/",
   "https://google.com",
   "https://google.com/",
   "https://www.google.com",
   "https://www.google.com/"]

/(https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?google\.com\/?/.examples.map(&:subgroups) # =>
  [[],
   [],
   [],
   [],
   ["http://"],
   ["http://"],
   ["http://"],
   ["http://"],
   ["https://"],
   ["https://"],
   ["https://"],
   ["https://"]]
```